# Acrobat Form Field RegEx Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, acrobat

I have a form field in my PDF that requires five capitalized letters as input, or nothing at all. Everything else should result in an error. I got the first part working, but I'm making some kind of mistake in checking for an empty field. Here's my Javascript:

```js
event.rc = true;
var myRegExp = /^[A-Z]{5}$/;
var myTextInput = event.value;
if ( !myRegExp.test(myTextInput) || myTextInput != "" )
{
    app.alert("Your order number prefix must be formatted as five characters, all caps.");
    event.rc = false;
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to remove `|| myTextInput != ""`. An empty string will not match your regex anyway.

Comment: An empty string should not trigger the error, hence the OR statement. Without it, the error comes up as soon as you reset the PDF.

Comment: So, any non-empty string now triggers the alert, right? Change the regex to `var myRegExp = /^([A-Z]{5})?$/` and remove `|| myTextInput != ""`

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting my answer if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regex to

```
var myRegExp = /^([A-Z]{5})?$/;
```

to allow an empty string match and remove `|| myTextInput != ""` condition that becomes irrelevant.

A `(...)?` group is an optional one because `?` matches 1 or 0 occurrences of the quantified subpattern.